# Open pdf file in Android and search for word in it

Tags: android, pdf-viewer, pdfview

I want to be able to open pdf files in my android and search for a specific word either in English or Arabic.. how to do that in code and what is the best pdf viewer to do search?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? can you throw some link of custom pdf reader with search capability ? Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This to open a pdf file

```
File pdfFile = new File("path"); 
                if(pdfFile.exists()) 
                {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
                    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try
                    {
                        startActivity(pdfIntent);
                    }
                    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MyPDFDemo.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    }
                }
```

You can find PDF reader based on your requirement from this [link](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pdf%20viewer%20free&c=apps&start=24&num=24)

Plz let me know if this solution suits your need

Comment: Thanks, your answer is good.. but I was searching for how to create my custom pdf reader with search feature.